# JSP out.println not rendering html tags

Tags: string, jsp

In a text area in jsp i am trying to dipslay some text in bold but it is not rendering the tags and displaying as it is:

e.g.

> ```
>   <% out.println("<b>"+Pattern+"</b>");%>
> ```

where String Pattern =ERROR

this shows as

> ```
>  <b>ERROR</b>  .....in the veiw source it shows like  &lt;b&gt;ERROR&lt;/b&gt;
> ```

Is it not supposed to work this way ? what are other ways to make it bold.

Comment: sorry....not properly formatted but it shows like

Comment: this shows as <b>ERROR</b>  .....in the veiw source it shows like  &lt;b&gt;ERROR&lt;/b&gt;

Answer (score 0):

Just try `<b><% out.println("+Pattern+");%></b>`.

Comment: Thats exactly what i tried....sorry im new to the forum so didnt knew how to post the code......

Comment: Tried the above code and even   <b><% out.print(Pattern);%></b>      but no change

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
<%= Pattern %>
```

its like printing it direct into the html Page

Comment: Even that is not working...its displaying with html tags..same result.......everything is inside a text area

Comment: What is in the "Pattern" variable?

Comment: Sorry.. i got the answer....I cant render html tags in a text area.    So i have to change it to div element. Now its working fine. Thanks for the comments